# Playing a sound every few clicks

Tags: javascript

I now have a div with a circle that, when clicked, will animate and turn on the sound.

The question is, can I make the sound play not every click, but let's say every 10 clicks, or randomly from 1 to 10 clicks?

Should I do this condition in the click function itself?

```js
var clickEl = document.getElementById("clicks");
let clicks = 0;
let listDiv = document.querySelectorAll("div");

A = document.createElement('audio');
A.src = 'http://www.freesound.org/data/previews/265/265296_5003039-lq.mp3'; A.volume=0.3;

for (let div of listDiv) {
  div.addEventListener('click', () => {      
    div.style.animation = 'Animation 200ms linear forwards';
    setTimeout(() => {
      div.style.animation = '';
    }, 220);
    clickEl.innerText = ++clicks;
    A.currentTime=0.09; A.play();
  });
}
```

```css
.circle {
  width: 80px;
  height: 80px;
  border-radius: 80px;
  border: 3px solid red;
  margin: 20px;
}

@keyframes Animation {
    0% {
        transform: scale(1);
    }
    50% {
        transform: scale(.8);
    }
    100% {
        transform: scale(1);
    }
}
```

```html
<div class="circle animation"></div>
<span>Clicks: <a id="clicks">0</a></span>
```

I am now adding one audio element, which will then be played. I want to add another one and have one of them randomly selected and played.

I try to do so, but nothing plays at all

```
A = document.createElement('audio');
B = document.createElement('audio');
A.src = 'qwe.mp3'; A.volume=0.5;
B.src = 'zxc.mp3'; B.volume=0.5;

let audi = ["A", "B"];
randomAudi = audi[Math.floor(Math.random() * audi.length)];

randomAudi.play();
```

Comment: What about, on each click increment `clicks += 1` and use the [remainder operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Remainder) to check if the click count is a multiple of 10 (with an if)

Comment: @evolutionxbox I now have the number of clicks counted, but how do I make a condition with this remainder operator? never used this

Comment: Use a [if statement](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/if...else) to check whether the sound plays. Look at the previous link to see what the remainder operator does.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I implemented that logic [in this sandbox](https://jsfiddle.net/6gd2ytjs/2/)

You can give it a try

Here is the full implementation with some explanation

```js
var clickEl = document.getElementById("clicks");
let clicks = 0;
let previousPlayClickCount = 0; //keep the previous click count for finding the next play
let nextPlay = Math.floor(Math.random() * 10); //set next play from 0 to 9
let listDiv = document.querySelectorAll("div");

A = document.createElement('audio');
A.src = 'http://www.freesound.org/data/previews/265/265296_5003039-lq.mp3';
A.volume = 0.3;

for (let div of listDiv) {
  div.addEventListener('click', () => {
    clickEl.innerText = ++clicks;

    //don't trigger sound after certain clicks (with random count `nextPlay`)
    if (previousPlayClickCount + nextPlay !== clicks - 1) {
      return
    }

    //need to track previous click count and randomize next play again
    previousPlayClickCount = clicks;
    nextPlay = Math.floor(Math.random() * 10);

    div.style.animation = 'Animation 200ms linear forwards';
    setTimeout(() => {
      div.style.animation = '';
    }, 220);

    A.currentTime = 0.09;
    A.play();

  });
}
```

```css
.circle {
  width: 80px;
  height: 80px;
  border-radius: 80px;
  border: 3px solid red;
  margin: 20px;
}

@keyframes Animation {
  0% {
    transform: scale(1);
  }
  50% {
    transform: scale(.8);
  }
  100% {
    transform: scale(1);
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="circle animation"></div>
<span>Clicks: <a id="clicks">0</a></span>
```

The debugged values in this screenshot

[image]

if `clicks` = `nextPlay` + `previousPlayClickCount`, the sound will be triggered. After that, `nextPlay` and `previousPlayClickCount` will be reset

Comment: Thank you, can I also add here so that one of the two audios is randomly played, I try the same logic, but it doesn’t work

Comment: Could you update your question? I could have a better understanding of your problem @stopwar

Comment: Added to end of post

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/70b2nfzd/1/ You can try this sandbox, @stopwar. Your problem was `let audi = ["A", "B"];`, A and B should be objects, not strings. Therefore, it should be like this `let audi = [A, B];`. By the way, your audio sources are not runnable

Comment: Only the first audio from the list is played, random selection does not work

Comment: Could you share another source of audio with me? I can play around with it again @stopwar

Comment: ```B.src = 'https://freesound.org/data/previews/624/624076_5674468-lq.mp3'; B.volume=0.5;```

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/61x4m3qk/1/ Could you try this? I played it a few times. The sounds have appeared randomly as your requirement